# Does jest run the wrapper functions used to test with "toThrowError"?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm having trouble working with jest `toThrowError` function.

I have a function that uses redis to set a limit for calling the function, that is, every time this function is called with a key, it calls `redis.incr(key)` and if the number is more than a specified limit, the function with throw `LIMITED` error, otherwise the function will return nothing.

for simplicity lets define this function like this:

```
async function fn(key) {
    const count = await redis.incr(key)
    if(count > limit)
        throw new Error('LIMITED')
    // do other stuff.
}
```

Now I want to test this functionality of `fn`, so if `limit=2` I call `fn` twice and if I call it again it must throw `LIMITED` error.

Here is my test:

```
it('should throw LIMITED error', async () => {
    const key = 'somekey'
    await fn(key)
    await fn(key)
    expect(async () => { await fn(key) }).toThrowError('LIMITED')
}
```

But when I run the test, it says:

```
Expected the function to throw an error matching:
  "LIMITED"
But it didn't throw anything.
```

This is weird because when I change the test code to something like this:

```
it('should throw LIMITED error', async () => {
    const key = 'somekey'
    await fn(key)
    await fn(key)
    await fn(key)
}
```

Then it throws `LIMITED` error during running the test and fails.

I'm not sure I understand how exactly jest expect functions work when trying to test function behaviors, so if there is any better way to pull this kind of test out, I'll appreciate good suggestions.

**UPDATE:**

I thought I could call `fn` three times inside the wrapper function used in expect, like this:

```
it('should throw LIMITED error', async () => {
    const key = '
    expect(async () => { 
        await fn(key)
        await fn(key)
        await fn(key)
    }).toThrowError('LIMITED')
}
```

But even this does not throw `LIMITED` error.

I even added `console.log` inside `fn` to see if it gets called, but it does not print anything when I put `fn` inside the wrapper function in `expect`.

So I'm now curious to know how does expect work when trying to test functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toThrowError` assertion runs provided function with `try..catch`, this is the only way to catch an error in a piece of code that causes an exception.

Rejected promises should be asserted with `rejects`, not `toThrowError`, because `async` function never actually throw an error. It's syntactic sugar for promises, it returns a rejected promise in case an error was thrown. `throw new Error(...)` is a counterpart to `return Promise.reject(new Error(...))` when used inside `async`.

```
async () => { 
    await fn(key)
    await fn(key)
    await fn(key)
}
```

cannot be considered a good function to test because it's loose and doesn't test precisely which call is expected to cause an error.

It likely should be:

```
...
await fn(key)
await fn(key)
await expect(fn(key)).rejects.toMatch('LIMITED')
```

Comment: so you mean my function does not throw error, but instead returns a rejected promise?

Comment: yes thanks to you, I updated the test and in worked like a charm. thanks.